# Facebook meta error, but it's not?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta

I have an error what I can't understood why with facebook meta...

This is the page: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmikrobusz-berles.com%2Fhir%2Fkedvezmenyek%2F2012-12-05%2Fteli_mikrobusz_berles_kedvezmenyesen_utazasi_iridaknak.html

This is my facebook meta.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Téli mikrobusz bérlés kedvezményesen utazási iridáknak"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mikrobusz-berles.com/upload/images/m1.png"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="mikrobusz-berles.com"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<p>
    A kedvezmény időtartama: 2012. Nov. 1-től 2013. Márc. 1-ig.<br />
    <br />
    Síutakat szervező utazási irodák jelentkezését várjuk partneri együttműködés céljából. A weboldalunkon feltüntetett áraknál is kedvezményesebb bérlési lehetpséget kínálunk, további részletekér vegye fel velünk a kapcsolatot!</p>
"/>
```

It's included between HEAD HEAD tags.. But facebook says :

> Meta Tags
>   In Body:  You have  tags ouside of your . This is either because your 
>   was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or you
>   accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either way
>   you need to fix it before the tags are usable.

What should I do? What's wrong?

Comment: Try to remove the <br /> tags in your description.

Comment: Yep, there is no error anymore, however it is not working. It doesn't shows anythink on facebook from my meta-s.. And it don't write any error... :-( Any idea? :-)

Comment: Maybe you can try it with another link. Facebook keeps some links in cache, so you won't notice any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the metatags should be on the `<head>` part of your site

apparently you don't have one

you can see what facebook sees on your site [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://mikrobusz-berles.com/hir/kedvezmenyek/2012-12-05/teli_mikrobusz_berles_kedvezmenyesen_utazasi_iridaknak.html)

edit: 
after looking in your page's source code - you don't have an opening `<html>` tag (right in the beginning of the page - after the `DOCTYPE` decleration

moreover - you have some junk printed in the start of the page, try removing it

Comment: Removed JUNK and added <html... it's working... Thanks everyone!